# What is the correct format for the System.exit() method?

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point, exit

I believe I'm not formatting the System.exit() method properly. This is how its formatted in my program:

```
  else if (input==6){
     System.exit();
  }
```

Is this correct syntax?

Comment: What do you mean by "exit the system"? Also notice that there is no `System.exit()` but `System.exit(status)`.

Comment: What happens? What does your debugging tell you? (are you sure `input == 6`) ?

Comment: Or maybe it's an applet or another situation with a SecurityManager that doesn't allow the System.exit. You need to say *what problems* you're having, no handwaving. Did you get an exception? Does it just skip past it? What is the value of `input`? (print it)

Comment: By exit the system, I mean exit the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[System.exit(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)) takes an integer argument, but otherwise you can call it to terminate your program.

Why do you want to call your `main()` method again? It is normally the static entry point to your program. If there's some code you wish to repeat, I'd suggest putting this in its own method and calling that (from `main()` and your code in the question).

Answer (score 0):

`System.exit(int status)` takes an `int` parameter. The status is not especially important; it's more of a feedback for the `System` if the `exit` went well. It's not important in Java; it's just something inherited by Java from older programming languages.

Just for your reference:

```
0 = fine
anything else = represent different codes
```

I would suggest using `System.exit(0);`